# Select MAX(ID) mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by

I want to group mysql record with idorig and select the max id in order to select latest record.

**My database content is like that:**

```
ID     | IDORIG     | MESSAGE    | STATUS
100    | 100        | azerty     | 2
101    | 100        | azerty     | 1
102    | 100        | azerty     | 1
103    | 100        | azerty     | 0
104    | 104        | azerty     | 0
105    | 104        | azerty     | 0
106    | 104        | azerty     | 0
107    | 104        | azerty     | 0
108    | 104        | azerty     | 0
```

My SQL request is:

```
SELECT MAX(id),message,idorig,status FROM messages GROUP BY idorig order by id desc
```

The sql returns the good id: **102**

But problem is that if I try to return status I got **2** not **0**

How can I change sql request to get the latest id with group idorig and even get the records of 102 not 100

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The error takes place bacause MySQL doesn't know which status from grouped records should results you. It knows that you want max(id) from group but according status is not obvious. Some SQL engines would tigger exception but not MySQL. It returns first record from group (status=2 in this case), I guess. You can do it this way

```
Select id, idorig, message, status where id in (SELECT MAX(id) FROM messages GROUP BY idorig)
```

MySQL is going to get Max(id) for each group (which is unique) then use it in parent query to select interesting data from this particulars records.

Answer (score 6):

```
select ID,idorig,Message,Status from messages order by ID desc limit 1;
```

or

```
Select ID,idorig,Message,Status from messages where ID = (select max(ID) from messages);
```

Comment: First one is the best logic among all.

Comment: I am quite not sure if this is the effect that author wants. Let's wait for his thoughts about it.

Comment: Yes I forgot to say, the request may return multiple results, I basically want to display a list of messages, grouped by ID selecting the latest id of each group (I edited the original post)

Comment: In which case I suspect @estshy `s solution below may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT id,message,idorig,status FROM messages where id = (select max(ID) from messages GROUP BY idorig)  order by id desc
```

Comment: You have group statement in subquery (which can return multiple results) and then you are trying to compare it to single variable. It is not going to work fine in all the cases.

Answer (score -3):

```
Select id, idorig, message, status where id in (SELECT MAX(id) FROM messages GROUP BY idorig)
```

Comment: This will surely give an error msg due to from clause not found.

Comment: And because of the multiple spaces before and after the query ^_^